# How do you allow a conversion to the base of a privately inherited base class?

Tags: c++, function, class, inheritance, access-specifier

I have a class `C` that privately inherits `B` that implements an interface `A`, as shown below:

```cpp
class A {
public:
    virtual void f() = 0;
    virtual void g() = 0;
};

class B: public A {
public:
    void f() override {};
    void g() override {};
};

class C: private B {
public:
    using B::f; 
};
```

My intention is that I want `C` to act like `B`, but only have access to `B::f()` and not `B::g()`.

I also have a function that take references to `A`:

```
void use(A& a) {} // function that takes any object that inherits from A
```

My problem is that calling `use()` with a `C` object raises the following compilation error:

```
conversion to inaccessible base class "A" is not allowed
```

What is the correct way to allow `C` to be converted into an `A`?

Comment: Once the class hierarchy is set, there is little or no need for up-casting, down-casting and side-casting. In fact, you probably do not ever need to use `dynamic_cast`.

Comment: I'm surprised the code compiles

Comment: I tried on MSVC 2017 and got: `example.cpp
<source>(27): error C2243: 'type cast': conversion from 'C *' to 'A &' exists, but is inaccessible
Compiler returned: 2` So your code doesn't compile. Which version of MSVC are you using. Are you _sure_ it actually compiles? Link [here](https://godbolt.org/z/W5BhcE)

Comment: Only a `friend` or member function of `C` can call `use()` and pass it the address of a `C`.   The purpose of private inheritance is preventing any other function from converting a `C*` to a (pointer to) a private base.   You could, notionally, supply `C` with an `operator A *()` but, if you do that, you are defeating the point of using private inheritance - so might as well use `public` inheritance.

Comment: Put this in C:  `A& as_A() { return *this; }`

Comment: What compiler (and version) are you using?

Comment: You forgot ````virtual````. Pure functions should be virtual.

Comment: @ArminMontigny Thanks. Sorry I forgot to include that but I edited it.

Comment: @TedLyngmo g++ 7.3.0 (MinGW) on Windows and g++ 7.4.0 on Ubuntu. It compiles on both.

Comment: @octopod Ok, strange. That's not behavior of g++ 7.3 or 7.4 on godbolt. Is it Ubuntu WSL (on Windows) or a standard Ubuntu?

Comment: Can C not inherit B publically but override g() so that it does nothing?

Comment: Sorry. I'm aware the example code doesn't compile and I'll try to see if I can get it working. I tried to isolate the problem from an actual project I'm working on and turn it into a small example but I guess it backfired haha.

Comment: The Ubuntu in question is Ubuntu 20.04 running in a VM. I guess I could make it so g() does nothing, but I wanted to have it so attempting to call g() causes a compilation error.

Comment: I've concluded that it really shouldn't compile and I'm somehow just "getting lucky" in my actual case. I'll take this extra problem out of the question since it seems irrelevant now.

Comment: "_I guess it backfired_" - :-) The power of the [mcve] strikes again!